# Android: Cheating prevention for "last level"

Tags: android

I'm building an Android game and I'm not sure where I should save something like "last completed level" or "remaining lives".

I'm pretty sure that I should not save this information in the database, because it's really simple to access an app's database with root access and some SQLite browser.
And I don't want to send it to a webserver, because the game should be playable offline.

What is the most secure place where I can store this information to prevent the player from cheating?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what if the player cheats on his own device, in an offline game?

Comment: [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12670282/2345913).... how about encrypting the data and then storing them

Comment: @laalto the point is, that I am thinking about creating a highscore table on the server. The game itself should be playable offline on the phone, but you should still be able to share your highscore afterwards. But still, if I don't implement such features: I just don't like cheaters / cheating :P

Answer (score 2):

You may wanna try one of the three options described here : 
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

Since android is base on UID, it is almost impossible to prevent root user to retrieve data, but you can still encrypt it .

I would go for the internal storage with encryption, and skip the content provider option due to the few data you will store

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and tell you guys how I implemented it in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a non secure storage (like `SharedPreferences` for example) but use a digital signature to make sure that the value wasn't tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use `Cipher` to save your game information file
check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782267/2773264

or you can save your file as Object by using `ObjectOutputStream`
(don't save String Object, save a custom class to prevent from cheating).