# What are the most effective methods to detect bot application presence/activity (client-side)?

Tags: windows, client-side, anti-cheat, anti-bot

What are the most effective methods to detect bot application presence/activity?

1 Considering the user can grant any access for the anti-cheat system in Windows (XP/7) OS.

2 Not taking in account potential amorality or illegality of methods.

3 Neglecting user-behaviour detections (like checking time between user actions or smoothness of mouse moves or using CAPTCHAs to detect bot or whatever).

Thus far I can think of:

- Checking INJECTED flags for mouse/keyboard events.
- Scanning processes list, detecting potentially "bad" processes.
- Checking integrity of application to avoid direct injeсtions.
- Checking if the environment is a virtual machine (to avoid false negatives of above checks).

Comment: Unless you install the equivalent of a rootkit on the user's computer like some companies (e.g. Blizzard) do, there is no way you'll catch much of a cheater. And even then, it's not precisely easy or realiable. Server-side data mining is much more reliable in many cases (and less trouble, too).

Comment: I read a lot about server-side methods of detecting bots (pure statistics compairsion mostly), but I know not so much about client-side checks. I think a rootkit-like solution is the one I need (that's why I mentioned #2 in my list), but i still have almost no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good post on this subject:  [How to prevent cheating in our (multiplayer) games?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960499/how-to-prevent-cheating-in-our-multiplayer-games)

My thoughts on your list:

- KbDllHookStruct Injected Flag - You'll get false positives for users with virtual devices. This is also easy to fake using several undocumented methods.
- Scanning processes - Also prone to false positives and potential legal issues.
- Detecting injection - Many legitimate applications inject themselves into other processes (e.g. DisplayFusion, dxtory, fraps)
- Checking for VM - Playing a game in a virtual machine doesn't mean the player is cheating.

A few suggestions:

- In your process, scan and compute the hashes of loaded modules (including your own) and disconnect/ban if malicious assemblies are detected. Requires a store of known hashes.
- Check for the presence of a debugger.
- Check for memory/hardware breakpoints.
- Server/client-side vector checks for speed and teleport detection.
- Server-side checks are easier to implement, maintain and as Damon commented above, are much more reliable. **Anything on the client can be subverted.**

Comment: Thank you for the article. I somehow missed it when searched the answer.I kno

Comment: w that my suggested methods are not very effective and that's why I'm  asking. As mentioned before, I am aware of the fact that server-side checks can be more effective and any client-side solutions can be abused.

Comment: "Playing a game in a virtual machine doesn't mean the player is cheating." Yes, but the other checks are not trustworthy in case of VM presence.